# How to include a “Show Desktop” option in the Alt-Tab menu of GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

This feature is present in Windows Vista and in the Unity shell for Ubuntu.

Comment: If anyone does an extension that enables that, then wait for it in the meantime no that's not possible, Mutter isn't Compiz.

Answer (score 3):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to minimize all the windows and focus on desktop.  It is set in **System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts**.

Comment: I just tried this on my Precise install with GNOME Shell and it works. I imagine it should work for 11.10 as well.

Comment: @Hey Gary, Works. Thanks. I shall stop short of accepting your answer though.